# handling a custom modal dialog in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I am in the process of testing a modal dialog using Katalon Studio, and the AUT is a web app that uses Bootstrap. I tried going to [this official documentation on how to handle such elements](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/pop-up-dialog-issue/), but that documentation was incomplete. It didn't contain instructions on how to handle my use case. I tried everything in it, and nothing worked.

Thus, even though my tests all pass (I did right up to closing the dialog by Clicking its "Ok" button), my teardown method (which logs out and closes the browser) is blocked by that annoying popup. At the end of the test, the "Ok" button was outlined a light blue, and I had to manually click it to get it to trigger.

The modal dialog's HTML code :

```
    <div class="modal fade show" style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Device Passcode</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>36395732</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A screenshot of the AUT, and the Katalon Studio screen, after that last test step:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by focusing on the dialog prior to click, and then right after, focusing back on the main screen.